# Changing only the body colour of UITableView or changing only the status bar colour

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios7-statusbar

I wanted to get a specific colour to the iOS status bar ,I understand it will take the colour of the top view controllers view .
And hence I can get this by applying the colour I want for the status bar to the table view ,which would look like this

[image]

But when it doesn't have any rows then whole table view gets that color (Obvious! but thats not what i want)

[image]

Is there any way to give colour only to the top part of the tableview so that status bar gets that colour or can i change the status bar color alone .
I have

> View controller-based status bar appearance

in Info.plist as NO .

Comment: download the image and add it, Or make the drive image public

Comment: @rajesh you can change only the color of status bar to/from white/black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply background color to status bar like following

```
UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Using the above code in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method would change the status bar background color of entire app. If you want to change the background color to specific view controllers, then you should follow the `@Lion's` approach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works ,
One question but ,I want this to happen only for this view how to fallback to the original .

Answer (score 1):

you should take one custom view in place of status bar and give background color to that view. and take your tableview just below this custom view so you not need to set color on tableview's upper part!!

View's height should be 20 and width should equal to screen width.

and position should be (0,0).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: where should I add the custom view ?
`self.tableView.addSubview(topView)`
or
`self.tableView.superView?.addSubview(topView)`

Comment: nop. in your view controller. add customview with frame (0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,20) and your tableview's frame should (0,20,width,height)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add one window to top status bar and change its color. It will look like this:

```
// AppDelegate.Swift
let topWindow = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(....))
topWindow.backgroundColor = ...
window.addSubview(topWindow)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden =  true

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView
if statusBar.respondsToSelector("setBackgroundColor:") {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

}
```